# hostsファイルの設定をしてアクセスしてもipアドレスで表示される

Tags: windows, apache, wordpress

VirtualBox 内の CentOS に複数のサイト開発環境ディレクトリを構築しています。
ディレクトリ内のパスを本番環境と同じに設定したく
Apache のバーチャルホスト設定をしました。

ローカルマシン（Windows 10 で VirtualBox を設置しているPC）の
hostsファイルに以下の設定をしました。

192.0.2.10 example.com

example.com でブラウザからアクセスすると
コンテンツは表示されるもののurl部分が 192.0.2.10 となってしまいます。
こちらを example.com でそのまま表示させるようにするには
どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

ちなみに WordPressサイトです。
重複している質問でしたら恐縮ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5):

hostsを設定しているのであれば、設定したドメイン名が表示されるはずです。
…ということはですが、wordpressに設定しているサイトのURLがIPなのではないでしょうか？
wordpressで設定したサイトにアクセスした瞬間、
設定されたサイトURLにリダイレクトされている可能性があります。
(他、Apacheの設定でリダイレクトされているなど、リダイレクトを疑いますね)

---

**追記**
原因が分かりませんが、設定したURLが原因でアクセスできなくなったのであれば
データベースを直接編集してURLを正すか
データベースを無視する設定をオプションに入れないといけないかと思います。

データベースでお話しすると
`wp_options`テーブルに`siteurl`と`home`の2種類があるかと思います。
この2種類の値を修正することで正せるかと思います。

`siteurl`が管理画面のあるURLになります。
このURLの末尾に"/"をつけてはいけません。

`home`が公開するURLになります。
このURLの末尾には"/"をつけます。

Comment: Myakuさんコメントありがとうございます！また確認が遅くなりまして申し訳ありません。おっしゃる通りwordpressの設定でサイトURL部分を変更したところドメインで表示されるようになりました。同時に管理画面にも入れないという問題もありましたがこれもこのあたりの設定が関連していそうで調査中です。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 追記しました。参考にしてください。

Answer (score 1):

URL を一括変換してくれる以下のようなツールもあるようなので参考までに。
[Database Search and Replace Script in PHP](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

日本語では以下の記事が分かりやすいかもしれません。
[WordPress移行時にURLをSQLで直接一括置換はダメ！ 「Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script」を使おう | infoScoop開発者ブログ](https://www.infoscoop.org/blogjp/2014/08/14/use-search-and-replace-for-wordpress-when-moving/)

Comment: こちらのツール使わせていただきました！DB移行などには便利ですね～サイト移転などには重宝しそうです！